# What are some of the criticisms of Noam Chomsky and his ideas?

Tags: chomsky

I absolutely adore listening to Chomsky and, of course, I agree with pretty much everything he says.

But that is because his and my ideologies align with each other.

However, not everybody shares my opinion of the man and his ideas, so what are some of the reasons people disagree with his ideas?

Comment: Which ideas do you mean in particular? His political ideas, his linguistic ideas, or his philosophical ideas? There are, of course, cases of disagreement with all three.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. Your question is currently too broad for this site, and there is already a [similar discussion on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/askphilosophy/comments/3ge6xl/what_are_some_good_criticisms_against_noam_chomsky). For a more academic source see [Chomsky and His Critics collection](https://books.google.com/books?id=5vsmSU_04DYC&source=gbs_navlinks_s).

Comment: @Not_Here I guess mainly it would be his Political ideas. We did touch on him during our first year but mainly my info on him relates to his video lectures and talks on YouTube. I listen to a lot of his and Friedmans lectures / talks and quite often find my self vehemently disagreeing with Friedman and strongly agreeing with Chomsky's ideas.

Comment: Wouldn't [Politics SE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions) be a better venue for your question then?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You need to focus on a particular idea of his.

Answer (score 1):

D+G have an exceptional reading of the Labov-Chomsky debate in the linguistics plateau of ATP. Their analysis of his linguistic theory is quite interesting, examining the Chomsky hierarchy in terms of their concept of [arborescence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arborescent).

(Possibly also worth mentioning is the somewhat-recent conflict between Zizek and Chomsky over factual references to historical events, but this is definitely less about linguistics than politics *per se*.)

Comment: Zizek and Chomsky arguing must be quite the sight, since both have a tendency to skew polemical. Have a reference to that handy?

Comment: The Guardian has a write-up here: https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/jul/19/noam-chomsky-slavoj-zizek-ding-dong